# jQuery Tag-it: How to store inputted tags in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just found this amazing plugin called [tagit](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it) and I'd like to get the tag values and transfer them into an object. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create a form

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="tags" id="hidden_field"> 
    <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and in jquery

```
$('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
    singleField: true,
    singleFieldNode: $('#hidden_field')
 });
```

So whatever you type in the filed will be appended to the hidden field. When you post it it will be posted to server.

Ref: http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html for more examples